# Can we pass data to DLLMain before it gets hooked?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, ipc

When a process from abc.cpp hooks a `DLLMain`, it executes the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`. Can we pass any data or parameter to DLLMain, so that it can be used inside `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`.

As of now I am using SetProp and GetProp of window API to share data, while considering desktop window as the parent window. But I am not sure about the pros and cons of this approach.

Thanks in advance

Comment: C != C++. Tag with only one of them.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/45672344/694576 if not a duplicate to it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can not pass a parameter when attaching.  You can set an environment variable, use the registry...an INI file if you want to be old-fashioned :-)

Or, you can have a function in the DLL which is called after it is loaded, and pass the information by parameter.

If none of these solutions address your problem, please explain what you are trying to accomplish, so we can help you better.